# Centrar imágenes y texto en un layout de 3 columnas

Tags: css

Buenas Tardes. Cuando intento tener una pagina con tres columnas .. las dos primeras tienen imágenes y la ultima un texto. Necesito que todo me quede centrado en cada columna (las dos imágenes centradas tanto horizontal como vertical al igual que el texto. Las imágenes no quedan centradas. Como puedo centrarlas. Gracias

Actualmente tengo lo siguiente:

```css
.column2 {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

.left, .right {
  width: 25%;
  display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.middle {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
    <div class="row">
  <div class="column2 left">
    <img src="../../Content/Images/Home/InicioExport.png" class="responsive-image" />
  </div>
  <div class="column2 middle">
    <img src="../../Content/Images/Home/BarraVertical.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="column2 right">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No las centres usando floats, usa flexbox.

Basta con este sencillo snippet en el row o contenedor de las columnas:

```
.row{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Ahora si quieres, que cada columna ocupe todo el alto, solo cambia `align-items: center` por `align-items: stretch`;

La magia se da por si sola, nada más. Mira:

```css
.row{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: center;
  font-family: arial;
}

.column2 {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}    

.left, .right {
  width: 25%;
  background: whitesmoke;
}

.middle {
  width: 50%;
  background: lightblue;
}

img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column2 left">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" class="responsive-image" />
  </div>
  <div class="column2 middle">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/400" />
  </div>
  <div class="column2 right">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ahora para centrar el contenido de cada columna, basta con que repitas las mismas propiedades en cada una, pero cambiando el tipo de `display` a `inline-flex`, así:

```
.column2 {
      display: inline-flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      align-content: center; 
}
```

Notaras que agregue además `align-content: center;`, tiene un efecto interesante si no lo tiene, te animo a descubrir que pasa si se lo quitas a las columnas.

Listo. Escríbeme en los comentarios si tienes más dudas. Éxitos!

Comment: No veo que las centre horizontalmente ...

Comment: Revisa de nuevo, actualice mi respuesta con las mismas propiedades pero en cada columna y puse un color de fondo para que sea más obvio el como se centra. ¿Es lo que buscabas?

Comment: Vale muchas gracias. Efectivamente funcionó.

Comment: De nada y si quieres, puedes agradecer dándome un voto positivo por mi respuesta.

Comment: Hola .. por donde te doy el voto.

Comment: Oye una cosita .. ya lo anterior funciona perfecto .. pero si quiero agregar un titulo a la columna de la derecha, como seria para que este quede arriba del texto original, porque actualmente lo coloca y seguido del texto. No le da un salto de linea. Gracias

Comment: En cuanto a tu segunda duda, a las columnas, colocale una propiedad llamada: `flex-wrap: wrap;`.

Answer (score 0):

puede hacer algo asi :

```css
IMG.displayed {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto }
```

Fuente : 
[w3](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html)